# producing related 'detail' for a summary query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Data:

```
ID          CITY         SEX            AGE
1           NYC          M              23
2           NYC          M              28
3           NYC          F              22
4           NYC          F              19
5           LA           M              29
6           LA           M              25
7           LA           F              18
8           LA           F              21
```

Query: I want to produce the **ID** of the youngest person for each gender from each city. There are 2 genders, and 2 cities in the data above (although there may be more cities in the actual data).

I want to solve this using both **Microsoft Access** as well as **plain SQL**

- Below is my solution using Microsoft Access. Do you know a better
  solution?
- I don't know how to do this with plain SQL. What is your solution?

**Data** (in Access)

[image]

**Query 1** (used by Query 2)

### [image]

[image]

**Query 2** (uses Query 1, and produces the **ID**s that I was looking for)

### [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the join on all three characteristics:

```
SELECT table.*
FROM table INNER JOIN (SELECT city, sex, MIN(age) AS min_age
                       FROM Table
                       GROUP BY city, sex) tA ON table.city = tA.city
                                                 AND table.sex = tA.sex
                                                 AND table.age = tA.min_age
```

The advantage here is that the subquery is not correlated, so it gets evaluated just once. A correlated subquery gets evaluated for each record in the parent query and can be performance-intensive for large tables and/or complex join criteria.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS:** Use sub query in join with `GROUP BY` but it will return the youngest all if there are more than one youngest with same `AGE`

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table_name t
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(age) age, city, sex 
            FROM table_name GROUP BY city, sex) t1 ON t1.age = t.AGE
                                AND t1.city = t.city
                                AND t1.sex = t.sex
```

Comment: I don't think it's enough to join on just age. This will produce a list of ages and pull all of those ages from the parent query regardless of whether they are minimums or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use `correlated query`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.age =
    ( SELECT min(t2.age)
     FROM table1 t2
     WHERE t1.city = t2.city
       AND t1.sex = t2.sex )
```

**Result:**

```
+----+------+-----+-----+
| id | city | sex | age |
+----+------+-----+-----+
|  1 | NYC  | M   |  23 |
|  4 | NYC  | F   |  19 |
|  6 | LA   | M   |  25 |
|  7 | LA   | F   |  18 |
+----+------+-----+-----+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/NLVR73155)**